# How do I describe this graph with an equation?

Tags: graphing-functions, visualization

[Spawn Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar9gv.png)

I need to describe this graph as an equation for my game in unity 3D, it describes the spawn of enemies in time. At first is kind of like a sigmoidal/power curve, but after some time it turns into a spline that goes up and down but overall increases slowly with time.

Can you help?

Comment: Maybe something like this: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%28ln%28x%5E2%2B1%29%2Bsin%28x%29%2C%28x%2C0%2C50%29%29

Comment: looks kinda like an exponentially decaying sinusoid with a linear offset. Or maybe, something like x + sinc(x)   ?

Comment: @BradS.: the decay law in unclear. Does not even seem to be monotonous.

Answer (score 0):

Your quick sketch is not sufficient to understand what you want.

$$x-2\frac{\sin(5x)}x$$

[image]

Comment: my level of approximation is unjustifiable. Apologies. The graph was actually supposed to start flat from zero.

Comment: @Pastille: is it such a big effort to crop ?